# How to perform a chai assert in Protractor/Gherkins against the # of rows in an element?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber, chai, gherkin

Pretty new to using Cucumber/Protractor/Gherkins, so please bear with me.

Anyway, here is the step definition:

```
Then('I should see {int} results', function (int, callback) {        
//assert that the # of results passed in, is equal to the # of rows displayed in the listings table
  expect(locationsPageObj.locationsTable.element.all(by.tagType("tr"))              
    .count()).to.eventually.equal(numberOfResults);
callback(null, 'pending');
});
```

And here is the locationsTable element as defined within our page object:

```
locationsTable : {
    get : function() {
        return element(by.css('.main .locations'));
    }
},
```

And within the feature file, here is how the scenario is outlined:

```
@Dashboard @Login @Users @UsersValidation 
Scenario Outline: Searching by location name
Given I should wait for the Locations screen to load in admin dashboard
When I enter the search box with content : "<content>" in locations grid page
Then I should see <numberOfResults> displayed

  @qa
 Examples:
| content | numberOfResults |
| test  |       0        |
```

Anyway, all in all, I'd just like to verify that when i enter in a string of text, there are 0 tr elements displayed in the table element.

Comment: Also, wanted to mention that i have confirmed that the string of "test" is being properly sent to the input field.

Comment: is it possible to send you some DOM structure. I think angular grid doesnt store row in tr format.

Answer (score 0):

Some code issues in your step definition:

```
Then(/^I should see (\d+) results$/, function (numberOfResults, callback) {        
    // assert that the # of results passed in, 
    // is equal to the # of rows displayed in the listings table
    var rowCount = locationsPageObj
            .locationsTable
            .all(by.css("tr")).count();

    expect(rowCount).to.eventually.equal(numberOfResults);
    callback(null, 'pending');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @yong. I added another answer below that works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Step definition that works for my case:

```
Then('I should see {int} displayed', function (numberOfResults, callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    // assert that the # of results passed in, 
    // is equal to the # of rows displayed in the listings table

browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(locationsPageObj.locationsOverlay), timeouts.EC_TIMEOUT).then(function () {              
            var rowCount = locationsPageObj
          .locationsTable
          .all(by.css("tr")).count();

  expect(rowCount).to.eventually.equal(numberOfResults);
            callback();

    });

});
```